# How to create reference field?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to create tiles and zones. Zones has to dimensional array of tiles. Tiles must has link to zone, but if i will create field "zone link;", this tile will create new zone, and if i will create "ref zone link;", compiler will say "missing '(' and')'". Compiler thinks that i am trying to create method that will return reference to zone, but how to create link to zone as field?

(This code written here, not inside any compiler)

```
using Something;
public class Zone
{
    public /*or privet*/  Tile[,]
    public Zone(short width, short length)
    {
        //create Tiles and
        //Give "link" to tile as "this"
    }
}
public class Tile
{
    ref Zone link; //compiler error: missing "(" and ")". he thinks this is method.
    //or
    Zone link; //logic error: infinite loop where every tile will create new zone.
}
```

please help me :(

i need this for unity, but please, don't say "unity already has tilemaps"

p.s. sorry if i'm bad at english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if i will create field "zone link;", this tile will create new zone

no it will not. It will use whatever `Zone` instance you pass in via the constructor.

Since `Zone` is a **class** which is a [**reference**-type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types) this will re-use the same instance whenever you pass it and actually only store the **reference** to it.

You already can tell this from the keyword [`this`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/this) which you are passing in as `link` anyway => This always refers to **this instance** of `Zone` => There is no creation of new instances.

In contrary to if it *was* a `struct` which would then be a [**value**-type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-types), in that case it *would* indeed create a new copy of the passed value.

You simply want e.g.

```
public class Tile
{
    public Zone link { get; }

    public Tile(Zone link)
    {
        this.link = link;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're coming from C++ here, in which you'd use pointers for this purpose. In C#, classes are [Reference Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types), so you can just have the following:

```
public class Tile
{
    Zone ParentZone;
}
```

Then, the statement `Tile tile = new Tile()` will give you a `Tile` object that contains a reference to a `Zone` object. No new `Zone` will be created when you create a new `Tile` unless you initialise one with the `new` keyword. You can pass the `Tile` object you want to store into the constructor for the `Zone` and assign it there like so:

```
public Tile (Zone parent)
{
   ParentZone = parent;
}
```

This will give you a reference to the `Zone` that the `Tile` belongs to.

Comment: Actually, in C++ you would use a pointer for this.

Comment: You shouldn't use pointers in C# outside of some highly specific contexts, and this isn't one of them

Comment: I wrote in **C++**.

Comment: That's why @ewerspej pointed out that in **c++** you would use a pointer to a different object as there are no "references" or at least they mean something different

Comment: So you did, my apologies. I've clarified what I meant in the answer to help make the link between the two concepts clearer